# DirectX11 Frank Luna - Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'Effects11d.lib' ParticleSystem

Tags: c++, windows, directx, game-engine, directx-11

Trying to get Frank Lunas http://www.d3dcoder.net/d3d11.htm sample code working.

Running the Chapter 20 Project and I'm getting:

```
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'Effects11d.lib' ParticleSystem
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you add the folder containing this file to your linker settings? Does this file exist? Are you mixing 32 and 64 bit? Note that `Effects11d.lib` can only be used in debug builds.

Comment: `DXUT\Core;DXUT\Optional;C:\Users\Ciaran\Desktop\Common;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)` it's there and being built in debug mode. (I can see the file in the \Common dir)

Comment: Maybe you are mixing 32 and 64 bit. You can't link a 32 bit library with a 64 bit exe or viseversa.

Comment: Heres the top level configuration properties: [image](https://i.imgur.com/4xe9RMV.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely missing the LIBRARY search path for his `Common` folder. This should be specified in your project properties under the Linker's *Additional Library Directories* property page.

Note that this also assumes you are only building 32-bit (x86) versions of the code since he didn't provide a 64-bit version of the `Effects11?.lib`.

*Effects for Direct3D 11* is intended to be built by the developer rather than treated as a 'system library'. You can and should build it from source yourself. See [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11/wiki). Alternatively, you can use the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fx11_desktop_2015/) package built for VS 2015.

> Also be aware that Frank's book is a little outdated since it was published before the DirectX SDK itself was declared [end-of-life](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/04/07/book-recommendations/) for some notes. Also it's worth mentioning that Effects itself is "as is", and HLSL compiler support for the `fx_5_0` profile is itself deprecated.

**UPDATE**: This [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fx11_desktop_2017/) supports VS 2017 15.9, VS 2019, and VS 2022.